# python.exe crashed when open long path in windows 7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python crashed when I did following steps:

```
os.makedirs(ur'\\?\c:\测试文件夹')
open(ur'\\?\c:\测试文件夹\t.txt','w')
```

You can see full path here:
http://psf.upfronthosting.co.za/roundup/meta/issue629%3E

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's a permission problem?

Comment: I'm not a Windows user myself, but wouldn't Windows report `WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied` or similar in case of permission problem?

Comment: please visit the link, it's a long path problem

Comment: Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit Windows? How about Python: is it 32 or 64? Are you running Python as an administrator or as a regular user?

Comment: 64-bit windows, 64 python and I also try 32 python, they show the same problem. The verison of python is 2.7.13 and running with administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a path length limit (which includes everything after the drive letter) of 256 characters; the issue appears to be that your path exceeds that limit. If you try to create that path manually via Windows Explorer, I think you'll find the path cannot be created there as well.

From MSDN docs ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)):

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by backslashes, and a terminating null character. For example, the maximum path on drive D is "D:\some 256-character path string" where "" represents the invisible terminating null character for the current system codepage. (The characters < > are used here for visual clarity and cannot be part of a valid path string.)

Comment: windows suport unicode path when you add UNC prefix before the path.  In my system, os.makedirs() and os.listdir() is ok, but open function is not ok.

Comment: Absolutely, but the problem is the overall *length* of the path, not the components of it. I've updated my answer with relevant citations.

Comment: hi @jshrimp29, please look https://bugs.python.org/issue18199, in my system, the unicode long path works fine for os.makedirs() and os.listdir(), but cann't for open function.

Comment: Interesting, I was unaware of the terminology and capability for extended paths. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all.
it's maybe macfee injected into the python.exe process.
see: https://bugs.python.org/issue30494